# Invalid Request creating a subscription with @microsoft/microsoft-graph-client

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api

I am using this [javascript tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript), and I have an error when executing the following code:

```
const options = {
    authProvider,
};

const client = Client.init(options);

const subscription = {
   changeType: "created,updated",
   notificationUrl: "https://4714faf8.ngrok.io/events",
   resource: "me/events",
   expirationDateTime:"2019-06-24T18:23:45.9356913Z",
   clientState: "secretClientValue"
};

let res = await client.api('/subscriptions')
    .post({subscription : subscription});
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
statusCode: 400,
code: 'InvalidRequest',
message: 'expirationDateTime is a required property for subscription creation.',
requestId: 'c20f75b5-0dca-48d5-a116-a34124bbfd58',
date: 2019-06-23T19:42:56.000Z,
body: '{
    "code": "InvalidRequest",
    "message": "expirationDateTime is a required property for subscription creation.",
    "innerError": {
    "request-id": "c20f75b5-0dca-48d5-a116-a34124bbfd58",
    "date": "2019-06-23T15:42:56"
    }
}'
```

Do you have any idea of the reason?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `"`. The node `resource: "me/events,` should be `resource: "me/events",`:

```
const subscription = {
    changeType: "created,updated",
    notificationUrl: "https://4714faf8.ngrok.io/events",
    resource: "me/events",
    expirationDateTime: "2019-06-23T18:23:45.9356913Z",
    clientState: "secretClientValue"
};
```

---

**Edit**

The response has a date/time of `2019-06-23T19:42:56.000Z` but you're requesting an `expirationDateTime` of `2019-06-23T18:23:45.9356913Z`. In other words, you are requesting to add a new subscription that will expire before it is created.

Try setting it a day or two in the future:

```
const subscription = {
   changeType: "created,updated",
   notificationUrl: "https://4714faf8.ngrok.io/events",
   resource: "me/events",
   expirationDateTime:"2019-06-27T00:00:00Z",
   clientState: "secretClientValue"
};
```

Comment: sorry, my mistake copying the code, that its not the error.

Comment: yeah, i've changed de expirationDateTime to a one more day in the future but the same error

Comment: At the line -   .post({ subscription: subscription }), instead try .post({subscription}); and see if that helps.

Comment: hi, AjayKumar  thanks for the reply, i've tried your suggestion but doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

You must directly pass the subscription object to the post function:

```
let res = await client.api('/subscriptions').post(subscription);
```

It works for me.

```
const options = {
    authProvider,
};

const client = Client.init(options);

const subscription = {
   changeType: "created,updated",
   notificationUrl: "https://4714faf8.ngrok.io/events",
   resource: "me/events",
   expirationDateTime:"2019-06-24T18:23:45.9356913Z",
   clientState: "secretClientValue"
};

let res = await client.api('/subscriptions').post(subscription);
```

Then Microsoft Graph verifies your request and sends back a validation token to your notification URL:
`POST https://https://4714faf8.ngrok.io/events?validationToken={opaqueTokenCreatedByMicrosoftGraph}`

You must send a response with the following characteristics within 10 seconds:

- A 200 (OK) status code.
- The content type must be text/plain.
- The body must include the validation token provided by Microsoft Graph.

This notification endpoint validation process is explained in the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#notification-endpoint-validation

Comment: thanks for the reply, i've tried with your suggestion but i'm getting:                                             ```statusCode: 400,
  code: 'InvalidRequest',
  message: 'Subscription validation request failed. Must respond with 200 OK to this request.'```

Comment: It's a good point: that means your subscription request is correctly sent! You get a 400 status code because you don't  provide a valid response to the notification endpoint validation request. See my edited post regarding this validation process.